# ColdFusion Array Forming from a variable

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to get the value of the first letter in my array. For some reason its just chopping off my first letter. Will someone please tell me where I am going wrong?

```
<cfset MidInitial = "Hugh" />
<cfset MidInitArray = ReMatch("[a-z]",MidInitial) />
<cfdump var="#MidInitArray#" />
```

Array Hugh 
[1] u 
[2] g 
[3] h

Where is the H going?!

Comment: ReMatch is case sensitive.  Either use (?i) infront of your regex or add [A-Za-z]  in your regex or do you just want the first character in the string?  If so, you don't need regex for this and a Left(MidInitial,1) would work.

Comment: Perfect that's what I was looking for if you want to post as an answer

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not simply using `left()`?

Comment: What do you want to do with values like 0'Donnell and O'Donnell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ReMatch is case sensitive. 
Either use (?i) infront of your regex or add [A-Za-z] in your regex.

Do you just want the first character in the string? If so, you don't need regex for this and a Left(MidInitial,1) would work.

Comment: Or `ReMatchNoCase()` with the same regex.